# Hiding file extension and redirecting to https

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

First off, I know there are many questions similar to this one. I've read everything I can find, but the solutions I see elsewhere don't seem to work for me. I'm really hoping someone can give me some insight here.

I am trying to use Apache's `.htaccess` directives to force *specific* pages on my server to use ssl. In addition to those directives, I'm also using some rewrites to mask `.php` and `.html` extensions.

I created a page, `https-test.html`. I want that page specifically to **always** get redirected so it uses https and so that `.html` gets stripped off, like `https://www.example.com/https-test`

However, I seem to always end up with a loop. Reading the Apache docs for 6 hours got me closer, but I'm still missing something.

Below is my annotated htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine on

# If port is insecure...
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
# And requested URI is /https-test...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*/)https-test$ [NC]
# Then point the server to the secure url:
RewriteRule . "https://www.example.com/https-test" [L,R]


# The next few lines try matching extensionless requests to .php files
# If the requested file is not a directory... 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# And we CAN find a .php file matching that name...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
# Then point us to that .php file and append the query string.
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [L,QSA]


# These next few lines were added by the previous project owner
# They're supposed to redirect requests like /foo.html to /foo,
# But I suspect these might be the culprit

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/$ /$1 [R=301,NE,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ /$1.html [NE,L]


# Next few lines are legacy SEO stuff, some pages were linked to as
# php but now are html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .php$
RewriteRule ^(.*).php$ /$1.html [L,NE]
```

So that's the code I have in my htaccess. And if I go to `http://www.example.com/https-test` in Chrome, I get *www.mysite.com redirected you too many times.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably just rewrite the code a bit. You are trying to match both extensionless files to php and html and doesn't look like you're accounting for each of the conditions. You should add a condition to make sure they are not tryiing to do the same things.

Backup your code, replace your code with this and give it a try. Clear all your cache before trying.

```
RewriteEngine on
# If port is insecure... redirect for a specific page
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^http-test/?$ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Next few lines are legacy SEO stuff, some pages were linked to as
# php but now are html
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /(.+)\.php
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]

# The next few lines try matching extensionless requests to .php files
# If the requested file is not a directory and php file exists
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.php [L,QSA]

#remove trailing slash and is not a php file 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/$ /$1 [R=301,NE,L]

#finally redirect extensionless URI to html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ /$1.html [NE,L]
```

Note I haven't tested this fully.

Comment: Thanks so much. Your changes certainly make things cleaner and easier to understand. 

Those rules work great for the `.php` and `.html` rewrites. Unfortunately, I'm still getting a redirect loop for `https://www.example.com/https-test`. I genuinely don't get it.

Comment: Change 301, to 302 to clear the cache and see if that helps. If it works then you can change it back to 301.

Comment: Cleared the heck out of my cache, tried different browsers, still getting a loop...

Comment: OK, so I started outputting some server info via PHP - even when using https, it's reporting https is "off" and port is 80. Wondering if perhaps there's some load balancing or other trickery going on that's causing my issues.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. Turns out the server environment I am in, on Rackspace, uses a load balancer or some other traffic routing, and the `%{HTTPS}` variable is unreliable - you have to use `%{ENV:HTTPS}`, per this link: https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/force-ssl-on-your-php-site/  - I'm going to post an answer to my own question in case it helps anyone else.

Comment: Yes if you are behind a load balancer you have to check differently. However didn't mention you were behind a load balancer. I personally let the load balancer handle the https and offload it there. That way I don't need to worry with it on the apache side. It will just forward the request to whatever port you specify. Also since my answer helped and is technically correct you could upvote/accept it.